# Programming using Structs

Tags: c

I am having trouble with a program I created for a project.I keep receiving a crash report when I try to print out the grade and the name, but I am not sure what is wrong with the code. Any advice as to what needs to be looked at again would be greatly appreciated. I am still trying to pick up things as I go.

```
#include <Stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define Sl 30

// Gets exam score
double Getscore()
{ double x, temp;
printf("Enter exam score:");

scanf("%lf", &x);
if (0.0 > x || x > 100.0)
{
printf("\nInvaild score. Please enter a vaild score:");
scanf("%lf", &temp);
x = temp;
}
return x;

}


 // Averages the exam scores
double Getavg(double a, double b, double c)
 {
double avg, sum;
sum = a + b + c;
avg = (sum / 3);
return avg;
 }

 // Claculates grade 
char Calcgrade(double avg)
{ char grade;
char A, B, C, D, F;
if(avg > 89.5)
{grade == A;
}
else if (avg > 79.5)
{grade == B;
}
else if (avg > 69.5)
{grade == C;
}
else if(avg > 59.5)
{grade == D;
}
else
{grade == F;
}
return grade;
}
 // Calculates gpa
 double Getgpa(char grade)
{
 double gpa;
 char A, B, C, D;
 if (grade == A)
{ gpa = 4.00;
} 
else if (grade == B)
{ gpa = 3.00;
}
else if  (grade == C)
{ gpa = 2.00;
}
else if  (grade == D)
{ gpa = 1.00;
}
else 
{ gpa = 0.00;

}
 return gpa;
 }

// Gets id number
int Getid()
{int temp=0;
printf("\nPlease enter a Student ID (A negative number to exit)--");
scanf("%i", &temp);
return temp;
}

// Struct
struct Student
{ int Id;

  char first[Sl];
  char last[Sl];
 double exam1, exam2, exam3;
 double avg;
 char grade;

  };
 struct Student Students[10];


   int main()
  {int count=0, a=0, b=0, j=0, i=0, k=0;
int temp=0, l=0, count2=0;
  double Class[10];
 double exam1[10];
 double exam2[10];
 double exam3[10];
 double Oavg, exam1_avg, exam2_avg, exam3_avg;
 double Cgpa, hold1=0.0, hold2=0.0, hold3=0.0, holdavg=0.0;
 double sum1, sum2, sum3, sumG;
 char str1[Sl], str2[Sl], holdg;
 char A, B, C, D, F;

 do
 { 
  Students[count].Id = Getid();

  if (Students[count].Id < 0 )
  {
count=10;

  }
else

  {

printf("\nPlease enter first name:" );
scanf("%s", &str1);
strcpy (Students[count].first, str1);
printf("\nPlease enter last name:" );
scanf("%s", &str2);
strcpy (Students[count].last, str2);
Students[count].exam1 = Getscore();
hold1 = Students[count].exam1;
Students[count].exam2 = Getscore();
hold2 = Students[count].exam2;
Students[count].exam3 = Getscore();
hold3 = Students[count].exam3;
Students[count].avg = Getavg(hold1, hold2, hold3);
holdavg= Students[count].avg;
Students[count].grade = Calcgrade(holdavg);
holdg = Students[count].grade;
 Class[count] = Getgpa(holdg);
 exam1[count] = hold1;
 exam2[count] = hold2;
 exam3[count] = hold3;

 a++;
 count++;

}
  }

  while (count < 10);   

for (i=0; i < a; i++ )
{ int sum1=0; 
sum1 += exam1[i];
}
exam1_avg = (sum1 / i);

for (j=0; j < a; j++ )
{ int sum2=0; 
sum2 += exam2[j];
}
exam2_avg = (sum1 / j);

for (k=0; k < a; k++ )
{ int sum3=0; 
sum3 += exam3[k];
}
exam3_avg = (sum1 / k);

for (l=0; l < a; l++ )
{ int sumG=0; 
sumG += Class[l];
}
Cgpa = (sumG / l);
Oavg = ((exam1_avg + exam2_avg + exam3_avg) / 3);

 printf("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------");
  printf("\nId   Exam1   Exam2   Exam3   Average   Grade   Name");
  printf("\n-----------------------------------------------------------------");

  do
 {  printf("\n%i", Students[count2].Id);
printf("   %.02lf",Students[count2].exam1);
printf("   %.02lf",Students[count2].exam2);
printf("   %.02lf",Students[count2].exam3);
printf("   %.02lf",Students[count2].avg);
printf("   %s",Students[count2].grade);
printf("   %s, %s", Students[count2].last, Students[count2].first);
 count2++;
 }
while(count2 < a);
 printf("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

printf("\n ---------------------------------------------\n");
 printf(" Course Summary Report ");
 printf("\n ---------------------------------------------\n");
 printf("\tExam 1 average\t%lf\n",exam1_avg);
 printf("\tExam 2 average\t%lf\n",exam2_avg);
 printf("\tExam 3 average\t%lf\n",exam3_avg);
 printf("\tOverall average\t%lf\n",Oavg);
 printf("\tClass Gpa\t%lf\n",Cgpa);

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: that's a _very_ long piece of code. It would be much better to give a minimal program, say 10-50 lines long, that reproduces the error.

Comment: that's a very long piece of *unformatted* code. It makes my eyes water looking at it...

Comment: There is nothing related to C++ in your code (In fact, it has several things that makes clear its C, no C++), so I have edited tags.

Comment: There were no errors that were given by the compiler. The program crashes when it gets to printing the grade.

Comment: Crashes on which line of code exactly?

Comment: The debugger says its a segmentation fault. I have limited knowledge of debuggers so I don't know where to look for that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what your error is, but a few things that immediately jump out to me are in `Calcgrade()` and in `Getgpa()`. In both of these functions, you declare the letter grades as `char A,B,C,D;` yet this only *declares* them but does not initialize them (i.e., give them a value); as a result `A,B,C,D` do not contain any values. I think you mean instead something along the lines of `char A='A',B='B',C='C',D='D'`; this declaration and assignment will give the variables actual values.

Also in the if's of `Calcgrade()`, assignment is done with `=` and not `==`.